# Trigger Segue from UIButton in TabeViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, cell, segue

I have prototype cell and in this cell there is an UIButton; so I need to perform a segue from the button to other controller, not from the cell. I tried to create an Outlet `@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!` and use performSegueWithIdentifier() method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecondController", sender: button)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

but I have no idea how to set the prepareForSegue() method... i tried this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "toSecondController"
    {
        if let indexPath = sender as? UIButton//tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! CoriViewController
            controller.coriSquadra = DataManager.sharedInstance.arrayCori[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

I also read that a solution would be implement a protocol, but I'm a beginner and I need a step by step guide.
Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your on the right track. In your tableviewcontroller define

```
@IBAction func clicked(){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecondController", sender: button)
}
```

You can keep the

```
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

line in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Don't forget to connect your ibaction to the button in your storyboard as well.

Comment: 's thanks a lot! But I have also a problem with the segue "uibutton does not have a member named row (line 8)!

Comment: change sender:button to sender:self

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to make the prepareForSegue working... could you help me with this other method? Xcode still shows previous error.

Comment: Change toCoriViewController to toSecondController and it should be all cleared up

Comment: Sorry it was a coping and pasting mistake... this is the line that give me error controller.coriSquadra = DataManager.sharedInstance.arrayCori[indexPath.row]

Comment: where do you declare arrayCori? You could try self.arrayCori[indexPath.row]

Comment: Finally I solved with this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341629/prepareforsegue-from-a-uibutton-in-a-custom-prototype-cell